# Filter file lists to get specific type files

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I got the following code to list files in videos library:

```
    var files = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        textBox1.Text += file.Path + "\n";
    }
```

Can I filter the files to get only specific file type files such as mp4 files only?
I know I can filter by using "if condition" in the foreach loop - I believe there's better solution and that's why I ask here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, new[] { ".mp4" });
queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
var query = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by calling the overloaded [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227274) and using [CommonFileQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.commonfilequery).

Comment: Can u give me full example?